# tooltip font in wpf

Tags: wpf, fonts, tooltip

Does anybody know how to change the font of tooltip for ui elements?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This gives you really big tooltips in all places:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <Page.Resources>
      <Style x:Key="{x:Type ToolTip}" TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
         <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24"/>
      </Style>
   </Page.Resources>
   <Grid>
      <Button Content="Hey" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Hey"/>
   </Grid>
</Page>
```

If you want to change particular tooltip you can define style closer to that tooltip, or place fontsize directly in the tooltip:

```
  <Button Content="Hey">
     <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <TextBlock FontSize="64" Text="Hey"/>
     </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
  </Button>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by adding textblock as tooltip's child element

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip>
            <TextBlock FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="10" FontWeight="Bold" Text="My tooltip text"/>
        </ToolTip>
    <TextBox.ToolTip>
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`FontFamily`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.fontfamily.aspx) property on [ToolTip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltip_properties.aspx)

Comment: I'd really like to know why the -1.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but may want to specify it's TextBlock.FontFamily or TextBlock.FontSize or similar.